# Telerik RadGrid - How to disable sorting for a row?

Tags: asp.net, telerik

How to Sort Telerik RadGrid, except top two rows? I tried to implement it on the SortCommand event.

Taken two tables, in the first I put the top two rows and in the second one I have all rows except the top two. Then I only sort the second table and finally merge both and load the data on a GridView.

```
var dtManager = GetGridData(); // To get data to load on grid

string sortOrder = Convert.ToString(Session["SortOrder"]);   
var dtManagerTop2 = dtManager.Clone();
var dtManagerExceptTop2 = dtManager.Clone();
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < dtManager.Rows.Count; rowIndex++) {
    if (rowIndex < 2) {
        dtManagerTop2.ImportRow(dtManager.Rows[rowIndex]);
    } else {
        dtManagerExceptTop2.ImportRow(dtManager.Rows[rowIndex]);
    }
}
var dvManager = dtManagerExceptTop2.DefaultView;
string sortBy = sortByText == string.Empty ? "Name" : sortByText;
dvManager.Sort = sortBy + " " + sortOrder;
var dtNew = dvManager.ToTable();
dtManagerTop2.Merge(dtNew);
dsGrid.DataSource = dtManagerTop2;

if (Convert.ToString(Session["SortOrder"]) == "desc") {
    Session["SortOrder"] = "asc";
} else {
    Session["SortOrder"] = "desc";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Behind code:

```
Grid.Columns.FindByUniqueName("Type").SortExpression = string.Empty;
```

or from the HTML:

```
<Columns>
    <tr:GridBoundColumn DataField="field"
                        HeaderText="Description" 
                        AllowSorting="false" />
</Columns>
```